# Defining a natural variable n in TI-Nspire CAS

Tags: ti-nspire

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a natural variable n in TI-Nspire CAS. For example I'd like to write:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define your *own* natural variables. However, Nspire has the following special variables you can use:

- @n0...@n255: Restricted to natural numbers
- @c0...@c255: Restricted to real numbers

You can replace the original variables with them by hand or for convience just put `|x=@n0 and y=@n1` at the end of line.

Example: You are calculating fourier coefficients and know that variable k will only get real numbers from Σ operation. Replacing k with @n1 will simpilfy the function.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lDnu.png)

(Calculator needs to be in RAD mode if you want to try)

Comment: Hello @wolfrevo thank you for your answer.Can you add an example please?

Comment: Hi! Added an example, hopefully it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Variables in NSpire store a value. A variable has no type. Solve might return @n1 in a result to indicate an arbitrary natural number, but you can tell solve to look for integer solutions only.